# VB Selectively Import depends on condition

Tags: vb.net, import

I am not sure whether this is achievable or not. I am working with a program's API, which have to different versions (v15 & v17). They both refer to a different `.dll` library but shared 95% similarities.

In working with this two versions, my code originally are separated into two class files depending on which version is selected, and the corresponding class is called in which the `.dll` file is imported using the `Imports` function. Apart from the `Imports` statement and some of the 5% namespace, the rest of the two class files are identical as they are doing the same thing with different version of the software only.

That create a massive problem as whenever one piece of code for one version is changed, I have to make the same changes for another version. I am looking to group those common codes into a "Common" module and leave those different ones stick with the version dependent module. However, those common codes would need to reference to the `.dll` library (depends on the version), my question is, is there a way to import two different library depends on a condition?

To clarify, I would want to keep the program to one .exe but not to compile it separately to two program. I have a selection box which allows user to select which version of program they intend to use.

Comment: hmm... funny enough the person who vote down did not specify why he thinks it's not useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you can use Conditional Compilation, that state condition when the file is compiled.
As this exemple :

```
#If FrenchVersion Then 
   ' <code specific to the French language version>.
#ElseIf GermanVersion Then 
   ' <code specific to the German language version>.
#Else 
        ' <code specific to other versions>.
#End If
```

Comment: Can you please explain this more? Is the "FrenchVersion" a global variable? And when I tried to place the `Imports` code below the `#if` statement, it grey out and it seems not doing what I want.

Comment: FrenchVersion is your condition that make you decide if you have to import a .dll or the other. I don't know in your case what it is specifically. And where it's write <code specific....>, you add the .dll import.

Comment: OK, what you mean is setting it as a custom constants... so when it compiles, it will select which dll library to import.

However, this is not what I want, because this will require me to create two different exe while I want to keep it to one...

Comment: Yes, depending on the condition that you write.